# Lookup range of words in range of sentences

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, range, lookup

Based on the following example:

[image]

I want to look up for words from the `$D$2:$D$6` range in sentences from the `$A$2:$A$8` range and use the value from the side column (here `Tag`). So far I'm doing this:

```
B2 formula
------------------
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$2,A2))),$E$2,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$3,A2))),$E$3,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$4,A2))),$E$4,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$5,A2))),$E$5,
IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$6,A2))),$E$6,
"other"
)
)
)
)
)
```

Although this works, my formula is as long as the number of lookup words I have, whereas I'd like to use a range to make it cleaner and easier to maintain (i.e. now if I add a lookup word I need to add an `IF` statement for that word in my formula).

**Is there a way to replicate above solution with a range-based formula?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this ordinary formula in B2 copied down

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(D$2:D$6,A2),E$2:E$6)`

See discussion and more about that formula [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/lounge-v-2-0/325172-***winners-announcement***-june-july-2008-challenge-month-15.html#post1597602)

Comment: I prefer this one over @bensheperd's solution as I don't have to use an array formula. To get rid of the static range I have `=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(INDIRECT("D$2:D$"&COUNTA($D:$D)+1),A2),E$2:E$6)`. What's interesting is that although I have `E$2:E$6` static, it does work (i.e. it looks up for values on cells below `E$6` :)

Comment: I would convert columns D and E in to a table [Select the range, Insert > Table and use "words" and "tags" in the header row], then your formula can be this: `=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Table[words],A2),Table[tags])` - If you add rows to the table those will automatically be incorporated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use array formulae. In cell B2, type:

`=IFERROR(OFFSET($E$1,MATCH(1E+37,SEARCH(D$2:D$6,A2),1),0),"other")`

and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> to enter it as an array formula.

It uses the `SEARCH` function to match each word in your list, and finds the last one which is less than a "big number" (here 1E+37). If there is more than one match, it will find the one which is furthest down the list (e.g. "a red car and a black cat" will return "object"). In the case that none is found, the `IFERROR` bit gives you "other".

Of course, you'll have to extend it as your list gets longer. (Always remember to <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> when you edit!)

Comment: I believe you meant `"In B2, type:"`

Comment: To save me from having to update the formula every time I modify my range, I have replaced `D$2:D$6` with `INDIRECT` and `COUNTA` which is working fine: `=IFERROR(OFFSET($E$1,MATCH(1E+37,SEARCH(INDIRECT("D$2:D$"&COUNTA($D:$D)+1),A2),1),0),"other")`

Comment: Yes; I thought about mentioning something like that but I didn't like to overcomplicate it since you didn't specify whether it wouldn't be regularly updated. `OFFSET` with a number of rows might be more 'elegant' than `INDIRECT`. I also like to use dynamic named ranges. Many ways to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used some VBA on a macro enabled button on the page labelled 'Update' so you could append the sheet as neccesary;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Target, cell As Range
Set Target = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    Dim term, tag As String

        term = "cat"
        tag = "animal"
        For Each cell In Target
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tag
        Next cell

        term = "dog"
        tag = "animal"
        For Each cell In Target
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tag
        Next cell

        i = "car"
        k = "object"
        For Each cell In Target
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tag
        Next cell

        term = "plane"
        tag = "object"
        For Each cell In Target
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tag
        Next cell

        term = "sister"
        tag = "person"
        For Each cell In Target
            If InStr(1, cell, term, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tag
        Next cell

    End Sub
```

The basic format of;

```
term= "cat"
tag = "animal"
For Each cell In Target
    If InStr(1, cell, i, 1) Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = k
Next cell
```

Can be copied and the variable values of term and tag changed for whatever search term and tags you would like without having to exist on the sheet.

It is also worth noting your IF equation is using a double negative, you can just use IF(SEARCH instead of IF(NOT(ISERROR( SEARCH.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like your `VBA` is going to require even more maintenance than my formula. Also, I disagree with `IF(SEARCH` being the same as `IF(NOT(ISERROR( SEARCH`, if the search fails, the former returns `#VALUE!` whereas the latter returns the `IF` false-case value: see for yourself `=IF(SEARCH("a","b"),"found","not found")` and `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a","b"))),"found","not found")`

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot Search returns a number.

I disagree about the maintenance, the code is easy to append and can scale easily to larger datasets however the Houdini approach certainly is more elegant.